# D3 Force Layout with Image as Node but Wrong Images are Appended

Tags: javascript, image, d3.js, svg, force-layout

I'm trying to create a force-layout with images as nodes that can be modified depending on user input (through a couple of checkboxes). However, when user is changing his/her input and the layout is redrawn, some images are showing up on top of the wrong node and I can't understand why.

The way I structured my code:

1. I pulled data from a csv
2. I created an "update" function that creates/modifies the data array depending user input
3. I created a "draw" function that draws the force layout every time the user changes his/her input (i.e. every time the function "update" is called)

The first part of my code seems to work fine. The array of data is created from the csv and dynamically updated correctly.

But when the graph is redrawn some images appear on the wrong node (even though the image showing up in the tooltip is the right one..).

Below is my "draw" function, I think that's where the problem is.

```
function draw(nodes) {

      var force = d3.layout.force()
        .nodes(nodes)
        .size([width, height])
        .on("tick", tick)
        .charge(-0.01)
        .gravity(0)
        .start();

    function tick(e) {

      // Set initial positions
    nodes.forEach(function(d) {
        d.radius = radius;
      });


      var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
                    .data(nodes);

      var newNode = node.enter().append("g")
                .attr("class", "node")
                .on("click", function(d) {
                                   div.transition().duration(300).style("opacity", 1);
                                   div.html("<img src=img_med/" + d.name + ".png >")
                                   .style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px")
                                   .style("top", (d3.event.pageY-10) + "px");
                                })
                .on("mouseout", function (d) { div.transition().delay(1500).duration(300).style("opacity", 0);});

          newNode.append("image")
             .attr("xlink:href", function(d) { return "img_med/" + d.name + ".png"; })
             .attr("x", -8)
             .attr("y", -8)
             .attr("width", 30)
             .attr("height", 30)
             .style("cursor", "pointer")
             .call(force.drag);

      node.exit().remove();

      node.each(moveTowardDataPosition(e.alpha));
      node.each(collide(e.alpha));
      node.attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; });

    }

    function moveTowardDataPosition(alpha) {
      return function(d) {
        d.x += (x(d[xVar]) - d.x) * 0.1 * alpha;
        d.y += (y(d[yVar]) - d.y) * 0.1 * alpha;
      };
    }

    // Resolve collisions between nodes.
    function collide(alpha) {
      var quadtree = d3.geom.quadtree(nodes);
      return function(d) {
        var r = d.radius + radius + padding,
            nx1 = d.x - r,
            nx2 = d.x + r,
            ny1 = d.y - r,
            ny2 = d.y + r;
        quadtree.visit(function(quad, x1, y1, x2, y2) {
          if (quad.point && (quad.point !== d)) {
            var x = d.x - quad.point.x,
                y = d.y - quad.point.y,
                l = Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y),
                r = d.radius + quad.point.radius + padding;
            if (l < r) {
              l = (l - r) / l * alpha;
              d.x -= x *= l;
              d.y -= y *= l;
              quad.point.x += x;
              quad.point.y += y;
            }
          }
          return x1 > nx2 || x2 < nx1 || y1 > ny2 || y2 < ny1;
        });
      };
    }
}
```

Any help/suggestions/pointers to help me understand why the wrong images show up on top of those nodes would be much appreciated!

Let me know if anything is unclear.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You probably want a key function (second argument to `.data()`) that tells D3 how to match existing nodes and data. The default is by index, which is probably not what you want.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff thanks for your comment, I'm still learning about key functions, but if I write something like: var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
                        .data(nodes, function(d) {return d.name;});                         That should work right?

Comment: From your code it looks like it should, yes.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff thanks it worked!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I was just missing a key function to tell D3 how to match existing nodes and data.

I replaced

```
 var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
               .data(nodes);
```

by

```
 var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
               .data(nodes, function(d) {return d.name;});
```

and it worked.
Thanks Lars!